# OpenNETCF.Button2: Code generation for property 'BackgroundImage' failed

Tags: c#, compact-framework, opennetcf

There is Button2 control on form. I have issue with changing its name:

[image: Property value is not valid]

or

[image: Code generation for property 'BackgroundImage' failed]

Button2 control Misc properties:

[image: Button2 control Misc properties]

How can I solve this problem?

As I mentioned I should add to my project  [DesignTimeAttributes.xmta](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6880658) file with Build Action: None?

I use .NET Compact Framework 3.5/Visual Studio 2008/OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework 2.3 library (Community Edition)

Comment: So it's failing when setting BackgroundImage in the designer?  What happens if you set it in code?

Comment: I have solved this problem. This has nothing to do with OpenNETCF. I have too much initialization code in form constructor that also calls constructor of parent form.  It is strongly recommended to refactor my code

Comment: Ugh! Hate stuff like that. Can you delete the button, save and close your project with all the errors, open it back up and add another button with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I removed all initialisation code (beside the call to InitializeComponent) in the constructor but still had this problem. 
I could solve the issue by adding a DesignTimeAttributes.xmta file with the following contents:

```
<Class Name="OpenNETCF.Widows.Forms.Button2">
    <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
    <DesignTimeVisible>true</DesignTimeVisible>
    <Property Name="BackgroundImage">
      <Category>Misc</Category>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Type>System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Type>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Description>The background image displayed for the control.</Description>
    </Property>
  </Class>
```